# Testing List of Tasks as if they we created more than 2 years, getting failures after running tests

Tags: apex

[image]

```
@isTest(SeeAllData=false)
public class EmptyRecycleBin_Test {
    
    @TestSetup
    static void makeTestData() {
        
        List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
        
        for(Integer i=0;i<400;i++) {
            Task taskToCreate = new Task();
            List<Id> Ids = New List<Id>();
            if(taskToCreate.CreatedDate <= date.newinstance(2022,12,1)){
            tasks.add(taskToCreate);
            
            }
        
        }
        insert tasks; 
    }
    
    @isTest 
    static void deleteMultipleRecords () {
        
        List<Task> tasksToDelete = [select id from Task where CreatedDate <=2022-12-01T12:00:00Z];
        Delete tasksToDelete;
        
        Test.startTest();
        
        List<EmptyRecycleBin.Requests>  requests = New List<EmptyRecycleBin.Requests>();
        EmptyRecycleBin.Requests request = new EmptyRecycleBin.Requests();
        request.listofSObjects = tasksToDelete;
        requests.add (request);
        EmptyRecycleBin.execute(requests);
        
        Test.stopTest ();
        
        List<Task> deletedTasks = [SELECT Id FROM Task WHERE IsDeleted = TRUE ALL ROWS];
        Assert.areEqual(400, deletedTasks.size(), 'Deletion was succesful');
    }
    
    @isTest 
    static void deleteSingleRecords () {
        
        Task tasksToDelete = [select id from Task where CreatedDate <=2022-12-01T12:00:00Z Limit 1];
        Delete tasksToDelete;
        
        Test.startTest();
        
        List<EmptyRecycleBin.Requests>  requests = New List<EmptyRecycleBin.Requests>();
        EmptyRecycleBin.Requests request = new EmptyRecycleBin.Requests();
        request.obj = tasksToDelete;
        requests.add (request);
        EmptyRecycleBin.execute(requests);
        
        Test.stopTest ();
        
        List<Task> deletedTasks = [SELECT Id FROM Task WHERE IsDeleted = TRUE ALL ROWS];
        Assert.areEqual(1, deletedTasks.size(), 'Deletion was succesful');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `@TestSetup`, `CreatedDate` is going to be `null`, as it is only populated once a record is inserted into the database via a DML.

Since `null <= date.newinstance(2022,12,1)` is `false`, nothing is being added to your list `tasks`.

Just so you're aware, once you insert your tasks, the `CreatedDate` will be set to today's date. (Unless you set it using [`setCreatedDate`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_test.htm#apex_System_Test_setCreatedDate).)

Regarding the rest of your test class, there may also be issues. Assuming that `EmptyRecycleBin.execute(requests)` is meant to empty the recycle bin, you're going to want to test that your query is empty. Once the recycle bin is emptied, there will be no records in Salesforce, even if you add `IsDeleted = TRUE`.

Also, the failure message in your assert looks wrong. I think it should say something like: "Emptying the recycle bin was unsuccessful". The message is shown when the assert fails, not when the assert is successful.